# How to programmatically add components or views inside other components/views in ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, view, components

I have a component say {{component-1}} which gets called many times and creates a custom-texbox container and label as many times as it gets called.
Now whenever a user writes something in it a suggestion box should appear below it. Since the suggestion box can be reused everywhere i dont want to have a separate suggestion box for each {{component-1}}, rather i want to have another component called {{suggestion-box}} that gets inserted inside component-1 i.e. the textbox container.

 I dont want {{suggestion-box}} to be inside dom at all since it is needed only when somebody types in it. I want to add/insert it into {{component-1}} when someone types. Instead of a component i even tried to use a view
Here are the different things i have tried and failed

Note: 

suggestionBox is the component

 textbox-container is an element inside {{component-1}}

1. Inside `{{component-1}}`
   `this.$().find(".textbox-container").append(this.suggestionBox );`
   where `this.suggestionBox = suggestionBoxComponent.create();` I have event tried `suggestionBoxView.create();`
   It gives me the error that i one view cant be inserted into another and i need to use containerView
2. `var tmp = Ember.Handlebars.compile('<div class=".suggestionBox"></div>');`
   `this.$().find('.textbox-container').append(tmp());`
   I get the error called

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
>
> I even tried to use view instead of component i.e. make suggestionBox a view but then again i cannot insert one view inside another
>
> I have tried a lot more things.
>
> Few points:

1. I dont want alternate solutions of how textbox and suggestion box could be created
2. How to pass information from a component or a a template to a view? Say i do `{{view "suggestion-box"}}` inside component-1 template, how do i pass values to it? Say for components we pass in the context like this `{{component1 sampleVar1=val1 sampleVar2=val2}}`
3. i Want to know how to programmatically add a component or a view and if it is a view how to pass the data to it?
4. I dont want to use container-view since it will cause more complexities, however if your solution allows me to pass value from {{component-1}} to container-view and inturn pass it to corresponding childView1 and childView2 then that solution is acceptable

   Just an update:
5. I even tried to use a view container inside the {{component-1}}
6. I also tried to use view block inside {{component-1}} i.e. 
   `{{#view "view-name"}}
   ----earlier component elements here-----
   {{/view}}`
   In both the above points "view-name" is a ContainerView which is getting inserted properly but the component element are not getting inserted

Comment: Do you have an example of what you've done so far on jsbin? How about using a handlebars if around a suggestion component/view which will remove/add stuff based on ur if condition.

Comment: my problem is in ember-cli so difficult to put it in jsbin. However will try to recreate it in ember js and get back soon

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with a `ContainerView` and the `viewName` attribute. The component or view can access the `ContainerView` or any other view that is part of a template through its assigned `viewName`.

Example,

**hbs**

```
{{view Ember.ContainerView viewName="my-menu-container"}}
```

**js** - then from the component or view

```
this.get("my-menu-container").pushObject(suggestionBoxViewOrComponent);
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yoyujeqi/1/edit

p.s. the context of the example is not relevant to the suggestion box, sorry about that, as it has been extracted from another answer related to adding a menu view dynamically.

Comment: Hey melc. I will try what you have said and get back to you.
However are you sure this.get("my-menu-container") will work?
this.get basically gets a property of "this" object. However since my-menu-container is not a property of my component i am no so sure of this

Comment: @Fishy you will call `this.get("the-view-name-of-the-container")` and this will return the view object instance of the container that has been added to the hbs template of any component. Then you can programmatically create the suggestion box and push it to the view container instance. If you have trouble let me know and I'll put up some specific code.